# Solving 2 equations - 9 Unknowns, with constraints.

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve a riddle with the use of matlab. 
This is realy more about matlab than the riddle itself (The riddle is taken from a daily newspaper).

The riddle gives two 3 digits numbers represented by letters. I need to find the digit (0-9) the doesn't participate.

> aba-dcc=efe   ;   aba+dcc=ghi

Now, I have 2 equations with 9 unknowns. 
I've managed to solve it by checking all permutations of the vector 0:9, in a while loop.

```
vecAns = 0:9;
P = perms(vecAns);
P = P(:,1:9);

A = [ 101 10 -100 -11 -101 -10 0 0 0 ;...
        101 10 100 11 0 0 -100 -10 -1];

resVec = [0;0];
found=false;

i=1;
h = waitbar(0,'Computing');
while found==false
        Res=A*P(i,:)';
        if (Res(1)==0)&&(Res(2)==0)
            break;
        end
        i=i+1;
        waitbar(i/length(P),h,sprintf('%d%%',i/length(P)*100));
end
close(h)
```

Is there a way (without adding mathematical considerations) to solve the problem. 
For example, I know that all the unknowns must be integers and within the range 0-9.

If there isn't a way. How can make it more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to enumerate *all* the permutations. You can start with the first 4 digits (`a`, `b`, `c` and `d`), and check if they produce a difference and sum that matches `efe` and `ghi`. You also need to make sure all the digits are distinct.

I'm not very proficient in writing matlab code, so I'll demonstrate it with C# code:

```cs
//aba-dcc=efe
//aba+dcc=ghi
for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++) // 'a' cannot be zero
for (int b = 0; b <= 9; b++)
if (a != b)
for (int c = 0; c <= 9; c++)
if (c != a && c != b)
for (int d = 1; d <= 9; d++) // 'd' cannot be zero
if (d != a && d != b && d != c)
{
    int aba = a*101 + b*10;
    int dcc = c*11 + d*100;

    int efe = aba - dcc;
    if (efe < 0) continue;

    int ghi = aba + dcc;
    if (ghi > 999) continue;

    int e = efe % 10;
    if (e == a || e == b || e == c || e == d) continue;

    int f = (efe/10)%10;
    if (f == a || f == b || f == c || f == d || f == e) continue;

    if (efe != e*101 + f*10) continue;

    int i = ghi%10;
    if (i == a || i == b || i == c || i == d || i == e || i == f) continue;

    int h = (ghi/10)%10;
    if (h == a || h == b || h == c || h == d || h == e || h == f || h == i) continue;

    int g = (ghi/100)%10;
    if (g == a || g == b || g == c || g == d || g == e || g == f || g == i || g == h) continue;

    Console.WriteLine("{0:d3}-{1:d3}={2:d3} ; {0:d3}+{1:d3}={3:d3}", aba, dcc, efe, ghi);
}
```

This completes in less than a millisecond on my computer.

**Output:**

```
717-233=484 ; 717+233=950
```

(`%` is modulus, and `/` is integer division. `continue` skips to the next iteration of the loops.)

Comment: This is great. I improved it a bit to fit more general cases, but the idea of work with only 4 digits was what I was looking for. Thank you!